# Need to make sub menu full width of screen

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, sass

Using css how I can make a sub-menu start from the left side of the screen instead of starting it from under the parent item.

```css
nav {
     margin: 0 auto;
     text-align: center;
}
 nav ul ul {
     display: none;
}
 nav ul li:hover > ul {
     display: block;
}
 nav ul {
     list-style: none;
}
 nav ul li {
     float: left;
}
 nav ul li:hover a {
     color: #000000;
     margin-bottom:5px;
     border-top: 1px solid #000000;
     border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
}
 nav ul li a {
     display: block;
     padding: 5px 15px;
     color: #000000;
     text-decoration: none;
}
 nav ul ul {
     border-radius: 0px;
     padding: 0;
     position: absolute;
}
 nav ul ul li {
     float: none;
     position: relative;
}
 nav ul ul li a {
     color: #000000;
}
 nav ul ul li a:hover {
     color: #666666;
}
 nav ul ul ul {
     position: absolute;
     top:0;
}
```

```html
<nav>
   <ul>
      <li>
         <a href="/view_contacts.php">Contacts</a>
         <ul>
            <li><a href="add_contact.php">Add Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="view_contacts.php">View Contacts</a></li>
         </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
         <a href="/tickets.php">Tickets</a>
         <ul>
            <li><a href="new_ticket.php">New Ticket</a></li>
            <li><a href="tickets.php">View Tickets</a></li>
         </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="/invoices.php">Invoices</a></li>
      <li><a href="/itemised_calls.php">Itemised Calls</a></li>
   </ul>
</nav>
```

here is a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jhmkqrye/1/ - hope it helps

When you hover on Tickets it's sub-menu starts from below the Ticket which I want to start below the Contacts from the start of screen width to end of screen width.

Comment: Typically when you want to force the position of an element to be something other than where it appears in the DOM initially, you would use `position` with a value of absolute/relative/fixed, and then give it a `top/bottom/left/right` to adjust/assign where it shows up

Comment: @Taplar I tried that but not working.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to set the parent `position` for relative and child's to `absolute` and then set the position using `left, right, bottom, top`

for example `left: 0;` would put your child item on the very left

edit: is jsfiddle correct? 'cause i can't seem to find any sub-menu on hover, and on click it throws 404

Comment: jsfiddle is correct ... you can also run my code snippet above

Comment: when i hover on tickets - there's nothing there at all tho

Comment: no, it is opening sub menu, you can check html code as well, it's working fine at my side

Comment: @uixpider I can't see the menu opening also. You have an error ` display: block ruby;`
The ruby shouldn't be there. I edited it.

Comment: @VVV display: block ruby should be there to display menu horizontally, you have removed the ruby and now it is showing vertically